# Не работает str.replace()

Tags: python, python-3.x

Проблема в том что `replace` возвращает `4 + 4 is &{4*2}, 5 + 5 is &{30-20}` вместо `4 + 4 is 4*2, 5 + 5 is 30-20`. В чем может быть ошибка (или не ошибка)?

Я хочу чтобы `replace` возвращал `4 + 4 is 4*2, 5 + 5 is 30-20`.
Заранее спасибо!

Вот код:

```py
import re
code = '4 + 4 is &{4*2}, 5 + 5 is &{30-20}'

searchAcB = [i.start() for i in re.finditer('&{', code)]
searchCb  = [i.start() for i in re.finditer('}', code)]
res = []
for i in range(len(searchAcB)):
  res.append(
    code[searchAcB[i]+2:searchCb[i]]
  );
  code = code.replace(
    code[searchAcB[i]+2:searchCb[i]], res[i]
  );

print(code)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вы в последний элемент списка `res` сохраняете подстроку между скобочек. А потом, по факту, заменяете эту подстроку на неё же. Естественно ничего не меняется. А если бы поменялось, то вы наступили бы уже на другие грабли - при несовпадении длин подстрок (исходной и заменяемой) у вас индексы поплывут.

Comment: есть ли решение?

Comment: Воспользуйтесь `re.sub()`. Она для этого и предназначена - для поиска и сразу замены. `re.sub(r"&\{([^}]*)\}", r"\1", '4 + 4 is &{4*2}, 5 + 5 is &{30-20}')`

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: Да и вообще, можно было `replace`'ами просто удалить ненужные символы. `code = code.replace("&{","").replace("}","")`.